# Eclipse tutorial: Can't add org.eclipse.swt to build path properly?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing the built in tutorial in Eclipse Oxygen. When I go to helloworld project -> properties -> java build path -> project tabs, the *Add* button is greyed out and I can't click on it. There are two things in that project tab that is called *Modulepath* and *Classpath*, and when I click on either of them, I can now click the *Add...* button and add the `org.eclipse.swt`:

[image: figure]

But I still get an error message, see below. The tutorial seems old and *Modulepath* and *Classpath* cannot be seen in the instructions in the tutorial. When I look on older versions of tutorials on youtube, neither *Modulepath* or *Classpath* can be seen in the project tab.

What is wrong?

**Error code**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at HelloWorldSWT.main(HelloWorldSWT.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Modulepath* is a very new thing for Java 9 (here you can watch a [short video how it can be used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8&t=37s)). It exists since the current version, Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a), October 11, 2017.

If you want SWT in a **plain Java** application (instead an OSGi application like Eclipse plug-ins), e. g. to run [these SWT Snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/), you have to add the following JARs to your Java build path (***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***), in the tab ***Libraries*** to the ***Classpath*** (not to the *Modulepath*) by using the ***Add External JARs...*** button. The JARs can be found in the `plugins` subdirectory of your Eclipse installation directory:

- **`org.eclipse.swt_<version>.jar`** (e. g. `org.eclipse.swt_3.106.1.v20170926-0519.jar`)
- **`org.eclipse.swt.<platform>_<version>.jar`** (e. g. `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.106.1.v20170926-0519.jar`)
- **`org.eclipse.equinox.common_<version>.jar`** (e. g. `org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.9.0.v20170207-1454.jar`)

Comment: Adding the "JAR" into "Classpath" in "Libraries" did indeed work! Thank you!

Comment: 3 years later I see the same issue. There have probably been more changes since then because this answer didn't work either. After wasting some time following various proposals I found the answer was to delete the file module-info.java. Now this answer works.